# Alter table modify column vs. multiply values query

Tags: oracle, alter

My application interacts with an Oracle database in which a table has 1 million records. The problem is:

In that table we have a column for numeric integer types.We want to store float values (2 digits).We could do that by multiplying with 100 (from the application) and store them in that column or modify the column data type.The question is :

What takes less time?
The alter table modify column or the query (update table set column = 100*val).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NUMBER` in Oracle has no intrinsic "format", i.e. its internal representation will not depend upon its precision or scale. The `NUMBER` 123456 for example will be represented internally the same way if it is declared as a `NUMBER(9,2)` or `INTEGER`:

```
SQL> SELECT dump(CAST(123456 AS INTEGER)) int,
  2         dump(CAST(123456 AS NUMBER(9,2))) num
  3    FROM dual;

INT                       NUM
------------------------- --------------------
Typ=2 Len=4: 195,13,35,57 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,13,35,57
```

The only difference in a column between an `INTEGER(7)` and a `NUMBER(9,2)` is that the `INTEGER(7)` has a stronger check constraint. Both columns will represent the data internally in the exact same way.

This is why you can **increase** the precision of your column of a non-empty column without problem, and the `ALTER TABLE` will only modify the metadata (dictionary tables) and thus should be instant with very little redo.

```
SQL> create table test (id number(7));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (123456);

1 row created.

SQL> alter table test modify (id number(9,2));

Table altered.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
    123456
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to modify data type of existing column:

ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Thus, if you want to have float column, you will need to create one, update it with your integer column's data, and drop integer column. DDLs are fast, however updating 1M rows will take time. You may want to limit it to 50000 rows and commit after each update, this way it will be faster:

UPDATE MyTable SET NewFloatField = OldINtegerField WHERE NewFloatField IS NULL AND rownum < 50000

And you can go another way of changing SQLs in your application and multiplying by 100 when inserting the data, and dividing by 100 when retrieving the data. However I would modify the DB to have the data going from one source and without the need to be interpreted in all places where it is inserted or read.

Comment: I disagree, you can modify a column as long as you **increase** its precision. Going from `NUMBER(9)` to `NUMBER(11,2)` is always possible. It is logically equivalent to going from `VARCHAR2(9)` to `VARCHAR2(11)`